# No wifi Ubuntu 14.04 new user

Tags: 14.04, wireless

there was windows 8 before on my laptop and the wifi was working without a trouble. After I ve  installed Ubuntu 14.04 the wifi connection is not visible (there is the icon available on the upper panel, but no wireless option visible).

Thank you in advance for help.
MB

Comment: Did you try the `Additional Drivers` utility? Anything showing up there?

Comment: could you please post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the output of `ifconfig -a` and see how many interfaces are listed. Do you have anything for `"eth0"`?

if not, then do
`sudo vi /etc/network/interface`
place the following lines (make sure to change the IP address according to Your Network Range at home as your router may broadcast 172.2.0.0 network or something else.)

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# Primary Network
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.2.13   #this ip might be different according to your router
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.2.1    
network 192.168.2.0
```

Now do

> sudo /etc/init.d/networking/restart

You may have to restart the PC. I hope this helps. Please enter the result whatever you get after doing all this.

Comment: hello, I ve made the steps (the outcome is in one of the answers above), but after putting auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
# Primary Network
iface eth0 inet static (with address, netmask, gateway and network addapted to my network) - than nothing really happends - even after the restart. Just after the Ubuntu is turning on there sppears something about B43

Comment: try `sudo ifconfig eth0 down` and `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`. then `ifconfig`. check if eth0 is available their. you may have to try `sudo  servivce networking restart` or the command mentioned in reply.

Answer (score 0):

ifconfig -a  eth0

> Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1e:68:87:3e:9e
>
> > ```
> >       UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
> >       RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
> >       TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
> >       collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
> >       RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
> > ```
>
> lo
>   Link encap:Local Loopback
>
> > ```
> >       inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
> >       inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
> >       UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1 
> >       RX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
> >       TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
> >       collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
> >       RX bytes:18033 (18.0 KB)  TX bytes:18033 (18.0 KB)
> > ```

Comment: does this mean that I have "anything for "eth0"?

Comment: if I put sudo vi /etc/network/interface I get the following:                                                                    
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                                                               
~                                          
~          
~        
"/etc/network/interface" [New File]

Comment: and than nothing really happends

Comment: This means the "Even you have added the static IP Address for eth0 adapter, however **it is still not available. try `sudo ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: not sure if you are trying this anymore however, still want to let you know that you can also try `sudo dhclient eth0` which must enable your network.